# Regex used rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What regex is used in Rails routes such that it works cross environments. I am trying to setup a middleware such that requests coming to `/:id:/show/details` does a reverse proxy to `wordpress.com/:id`, was wondering if I can use something Rails has already built-in for this use case

Comment: please accept the answer if it resolved your issue.

Comment: no it did not, this will lead to a 301. reverse proxy will give me a 200 okay status @Abhinay

Comment: Aah got it, then you may need something like this one: https://github.com/waterlink/rack-reverse-proxy or this one: https://github.com/axsuul/rails-reverse-proxy

Answer (score 0):

You can always do something like this:

```
get '/:id/show/details', to: redirect{|params| "https://wordpress.com/mypage/#{params[:id]}"}
```